# What do the parentheses do in vim's normal mode?

Tags: vim

Accidentally pressed `)` while in normal mode, and can't find any documentation anywhere explaining what they do. The jumps seem so random

Comment: "*can't find any documentation anywhere*" - `:help )`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parens form « sentence motions ». Right jumps to end of sentence, left to beginning. There are also `is` and `as` text objects.

Sentences are best used with text (like comments or prose), not code.

As mentioned in the comments, you can *always* do `:help something i dont understand`—`:h )` gives the right docs.